# Fast sort multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I need to sort a multidimensional array according to the values in the first sub-array, as fast as possible (the line is applied millions of times).

Below is my original line, and my attempt at improving its performance which is not working. As far as I can see, my `numpy` approach is only sorting properly the first sub-array, and none of the remaining ones.

What am I doing wrong and how can I improve the performance of the sorting?

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some random data.
# I receive the actual data as a list, hence the .tolist()
aa = np.random.rand(10, 2000).tolist()

# This is the original line I need to process faster.
b1 = zip(*sorted(zip(*aa), key=lambda x: x[0]))

# This is my attempt at improving the above line's performance
b2 = np.sort(np.asarray(aa).T, axis=0).T

# Check if all sub-arrays are equal
for a, b in zip(*[b1, b2]):
    print(np.array_equal(a, b))
```

Comment: Right off the bat, you can try replacing `lambda x: x[0]` with `operator.itemgetter(0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now. But why is the `numpy` approach not working? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still a novice when it comes to `lambdas`, but from what little I understand from your code - It seems in your `lambda` method, you are using `x[0]` to get the sort keys and then using those to pull values  off each element in `aa`. In NumPy terms, that translates to getting the sort indices for the first row in the array version and then indexing into each row (since each element of `aa` becomes each row of array `a`). That's basically column-indexing. Also, it seems `sorted` maintains order for identical elements. So, we need to use `argsort(kind='mergesort')`.

Thus, we can simply do -

```
a[:, a[0].argsort(kind='mergesort')] # a = np.array(aa)
```

In your NumPy code, you are doing nothing of those sorts, so not giving the correct results.

Comment: Thanks! This is ~20X faster than my original approach. Could you explain what am I doing wrong with my use of `numpy` and transposing? That way I can learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation Divakar!